# How can I maip requested url to specific another url in php?

Tags: php, url, request, url-routing, httprequest

I'm beginner in php and need to know how can I change url for specific page
assume I have home.php and url for this page is
localhost:8080/webtemp/View/Home.php

and i need user when request this page just type 
ex: http:\webtemp.com

how can I do this.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking for a domain or a path rewrite :)

Comment: `http:\webtemp.com` would not work `http://webtemp.localhost:8080` may work

Comment: looking for path rewrite

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is when user calls http://webtemp.com your index.php show content from another php running in another webserver (http://localhost:8080/webtemp/View/Home.php), then 
you can load remote content through [file_get_contents function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). However what you will be doing will be more like a reverse proxy than maping a php url.

In the other hand if what you want is when user calls http://webtemp.com show conteng generated from http://webtemp.com/webtemp/View/Home.php, and you are using Apache, you can do that with htaccess. 
Place inside your .htaccess on your root dir:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /webtemp/View/Home.php
```

If it non of the above what you want, then I'm lost. Please clarify.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is looking for. Albeit, the post isn't the most clear.

Comment: True, I was in doubt but was unable to ask clarification as I'm a new user and can't comment on people questions.